# How do add +1 to the PositiveIntegerField model field when adding each new Post?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `Posts` model. And field `Order = models.PositiveIntegerField()` has been created for arbitrary sorting.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Order = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

**Objective:** in the model, overriding the `save` method, do add the index +1 (from the last available index of Posts) to this field when adding each new `Post`.

That is, each post must have an Order-index, and if there are already 3 posts on the site, then when the fourth is added - index 4 is added to his the field, and so on.

"1" index in Order field (1st post), "2" index in Order field (2nd post) etc 3, 4, 5... similar ID.

Help implement this logic im method `save`. It seems simple, but I don't know how to approach it.

I understand that in the model and what I do:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = self.order.objects.all()
    last_item = qs.latest(self.order)
    last_item.order += 1
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But this don't work. Help me, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    model_class = type(self)
    last_item = model_class.objects.order_by('-order').first()
    if last_item is not None:
        self.order = last_item.order + 1

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You get the class (`model_class`), then you sort descendingly by `order` field and get the first instance.

I suggest you add an Index for the `order` field, if you don't have it already, because this field will be queried every time a new instance is created. Without indexes the performance might suffer, specially if there are many rows.

Comment: Thanks, it's work it, but - return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: @Elliot13 the `save()` method does not return anything, so no need to use `return`; the return statement will not create problems, but it is not necessary.

Comment: @Elliot13 and `super()` can be used without arguments, if your class structure is simple like this; it works if you pass the arguments `super(Post, self)`, but it also works without them

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you! @Ralf

Comment: Why `model_class = type(self)` `model_class.objects.order_by('-order').first()` not just `Post.objects.order_by('-order').first()` ???

Comment: @Elliot13 That is a preference of mine, but not strictly necessary; the `save()` method is inside the `Post` class so it already knows what class it has. This helps me to reduce errors, so if I for example change the model name to `Post2` for some reason, then I need to change less parts in the code to the new name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought the reason was more complicated and I wanted to know.

Comment: Ever heard of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Don't just give OP what they want, it seems they just want an autoincrementing PK. Plus your solution is prone to race conditions.