# How to avoid double saving after defining the `Save` method on the Model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have defined a `Save` method in my `model` for the `order` fields.

Now, when I do some manipulations with the `Order` field in `View` and call `save()` - I save **twice** - in `View` save() and `Model` save().

Because of this, the problem! How to solve this problem? How to make `Save` work only when creating a model object? And don't work `save` when I `save()` in `Views`

[save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69380497/how-do-add-1-to-the-positiveintegerfield-model-field-when-adding-each-new-post)

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    model_class = type(self)
    last_item = model_class.objects.order_by('-order').first()
    if last_item is not None:
        self.order = last_item.order += 1

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I don't understand. Could you add the code of your model `save()` method?

Comment: @Ralf Yes, is your code

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It seems you just want an autoincrementing primary key? Also your solution is prone to race conditions, it is highly likely that multiple instances may end up with the same value for `order`... See [How do I make an auto increment integer field in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128899/how-do-i-make-an-auto-increment-integer-field-in-django)

Comment: if i will use auto increments `models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` - can i will change the values in `views`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you want the extra code in the save method to only run on creation, not when updating the model instance.

Before the object is created in the database, its PK is `None`. You could use that to check if it is a creation or update operation.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk is None:
        # this code will only be executed when the object is created
        model_class = type(self)
        last_item = model_class.objects.order_by('-order').first()
        if last_item is not None:
            self.order = last_item.order + 1
        else:
            self.order = 0

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Other option: using [`Model._state`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model._state)

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907695/in-a-django-model-custom-save-method-how-should-you-identify-a-new-object